# Highcharts Heatmap background color when invalid data

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

When I render an invalid data like a string on Highcharts Heatmap, it shows the string with a black background. Below is an example of an invalid data:

```
data: [[0, 0, "A"], [1, 0, "B"], [2, 0, "C"], [3, 0, "D"], [4, 0, "E"]]
```

Can I change this default behavior and show another background color instead of black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a unsupported value the `ColorAxis.toColor` function returns `rgb(NaN,NaN,NaN)` as the color of the cell. 
By writing a rather small wrapper for that function you could intercept string values and return a color of your choice.

For example ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tcd60rpL/5/)):

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.ColorAxis.prototype, 'toColor', function (proceed, value, point) {
        if(typeof value === 'string') // String value -> Return pink
            return 'rgb(255,105,180)'; 
        else // Normal value -> Proceed as usual
            return proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks for this beautiful answer!